# Determine if any property value is not null and matches value in another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's say I have a `List<string>` that looks like this:

```
var lstStuff = new List<String>(){"test", "value", "other"};
```

I also have a Model Class that looks like this

```
public class Codes {
    public string Code     {get;set;}
    public string? HaveVal {get;set;}
}
```

In my C# method I have something like this. What I am trying to achieve is to return a `TRUE` or `FALSE` if any single item in `lstStuff` has a `HaveVal` in `lstCode`

```
public bool DoesAnyCodeHaveAValue
{
    var lstStuff = new List<String(){"Code1","Code2","Code3"};

    List<Code> lstCode = new List<Code>() {
                            new Code() {Code = "Code1", HaveVal=null},
                            new Code() {Code = "Code1", HaveVal="yes"},
                            new Code() {Code = "Code1", HaveVal="yes"}
                          };
 }
```

Here's my code to achieve this, but I was wondering if there is a LINQ way of doing this.

```
 var isVal = false;

 foreach (var val in lstStuff){
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lstCode.Where(x=>x.Code=val).Select(y=>y.HaveVal).ToString())){
       isVal=true;
    }
 }

 return isVal;
```

Is there a shorter way to do this, without needing to loop?

Comment: You always need to loop here. There are solutions you might not see it explicitly but it will still be there.

Comment: Strings are not value types. There is no `string?`, because string variables can already be `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0) twice::

```
bool isVal = lstCode.Any(c => lstStuff.Any(s => s == c.Code));
```

If you don't want null values you can filter them out too:

```
bool isVal = lstCode.Any(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.HaveVal) 
                                 && lstStuff.Any(s => s == c.Code));
```

[Here's a demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H59QRh)